# Search String in Excel with python

Tags: python, excel, search, openpyxl

My program has as the Output a String (the UID in the image). Now I need to compare the UID to the Excel file to get the correct Name. So the final `print()` should write the Name next to the right UID. In this case Max Mustermann. I used `openpyxl` for the rest of the excel work so it would be nice if it is possible in `openpyxl`.

[image]

The sheet is named "Data"

I'm new to Python and OpenPyXL so I am clueless right now. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reference, the following snippet reads data from an excel file which has format as your screenshot, then search and display a specific UID with corresponding Name.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb['DATA']

is_match = False

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=len(list(ws.rows)), max_col=2):
    for cell in row:
        if is_match:
            print(cell.value)
            break
        if cell.value == 'Specific UID':
            is_match = True
            print(cell.value, end=' - ')
    if is_match:
        break

wb.close()
```

Comment: `len(list(ws.rows))` really? This is not a good idea and not necessary. Neither is checking for the same condition twice.

Comment: You're right @CharlieClark, thanks. I tried `len(ws['A'])` instead and it is faster based on my measurement. Though should you have any other better solution please also share it here

Comment: But you don't need it at all as openpyxl will use the whole sheet unless otherwise specified, `ws["A"]` does anyway.